# NextJS - Adding Custom pages/_app.js getInitialProps does not allow us to write getStaticProps on any of the pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am new to NextJS.

Problem: I have a custom App i.e. pages/_app.js because I need the Header and Footer for entire website to be served ffrom one common place. I have a NAVBAR(it is a NORMAL react component i.e. not in pages folder) for which my menu items will be populated from an API Call. Now I want to invoke that API from _app.js for which I enabled getInitialProps(). I have 2 issues:

1. Do we get a BUILD time error if we have written getStaticProps in ANY of the other pages? Meaning with this option enabled in _app.js ; am I only left with SSR and I lose on SSG and ISR?
2. I want to call the NavBAr API on the server side; can you suggest me an better approach where it can be invoked on Server? That way I dont need to ENABLE the getInitialProps in _app.js?

Comment: What happens currently when you try to build the app (via `next build` command)?

Comment: Also might be worth visiting https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - adding more details to the question will most likely raise the chances of others being able to provide helpful advice

Comment: Layouts - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts - You'd only use _getInitialProps if your data is static at build.  This disables automatic optimizations by Next.   If you have dynamic data and want to build your app statically (SSG), you'd use client-side data fetching with something like Apollo query hooks or fetch inside your layout.

Comment: Thanks @SeanW. This was of great help. I just wanted to be assured what I am doing was right. I have invoked API in Layout to invoke the NavBar API as you mentioned. Cos the API response will keep changing every hour based on some backend logic.